# Any nice record Handling tricks in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, record

I'm aware of partial updates for records like :

```
data A a b = A { a :: a, b :: b }
x = A { a=1,b=2 :: Int }
y = x { b = toRational (a x) + 4.5 }
```

Are there any tricks for doing only partial initialization, creating a subrecord type, or doing (de)serialization on subrecord?

In particular, I found that the first of these lines works but the second does not :

```
read "A {a=1,b=()}" :: A Int ()
read "A {a=1}" :: A Int ()
```

You could always massage such input using a regular expression, but I'm curious what Haskell-like options exist.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for here. A generic deserialisation mechanism that can parse `A {a=1}`? I wouldn't recommend actually storing any data in the Haskell `Show` format; it won't be compact at all, and parsing it in anything other than Haskell will be a pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial initialisation works fine: `A {a=1}` is a valid expression of type `A Int ()`; the `Read` instance just doesn't bother parsing anything the `Show` instance doesn't output. The `b` field is initialised to `error "..."`, where the string contains file/line information to help with debugging.

You generally shouldn't be using `Read` for any real-world parsing situations; it's there for toy programs that have really simple serialisation needs and debugging.

I'm not sure what you mean by "subrecord", but if you want serialisation/deserialisation that can cope with "upgrades" to the record format to contain more information while still being able to process old (now "partial") serialisations, then the [safecopy](http://acid-state.seize.it/safecopy) library does just that.

Comment: Ahh, I simply hadn't gotten past the warning that occurs when you make one and the exception that show throws.  And yes safecopy looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leave some value in Haskell "uninitialized" (it would not be possible to "initialize" it later anyway, since Haskell is pure). If you want to provide "default" values for the fields, then you can make some "default" value for your record type, and then do a partial update on that default value, setting only the fields you care about. I don't know how you would implement `read` for this in a simple way, however.